# how to fix this error?? > Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I want to run React Native application. Did everything in order as described in the official documentation React Native

I was reading a possible problem when creating an AVD manager and in settings just need to choose "use host GPU". Since I have an android studio version of 3.4 GPU settings I did not find and found and chose Hardware-Gles 2.0 but the error still remained.

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
at runOnAllDevices (/Users/obaranni/Anastasiia/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (/Users/obaranni/Anastasiia/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:137:41)
at /Users/obaranni/Anastasiia/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:103:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/obaranni/Anastasiia/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Comment: Have you started a simulator or connected a device?

Comment: Run adb device cmd and make sure your device is connected or simulator is running. Then let me know

Comment: no, I just wrote the command at the terminal and I created a device in the android studio

Comment: Did you see any device connected while running adb device

Comment: no, I tried to connect via the mobile device but it is not visible. On the phone, the developer settings and the hibernate is turned on.

Comment: it works!!!! I have enabled the developer settings on phone, in the bash has launched and everything has appeared. thank yoouuu